# Which language to pick, that can listen for inputs from a Bluetooth audio source?

Tags: windows, events, bluetooth, keyevent

I have a Windows tablet in my car. It is connected to the car via Bluetooth, so I can skip tracks, change volume, play/pause, and so on using my steering wheel. I want to fire an event depending on which button was pressed.

So far I've tried intercepting inputs and keypresses globally using:

- NodeJS (using a library called [iohook](https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook))

  - Listens for keypresses on the system, so I can always listen for keypresses (basically a keylogger)
  - Works great if I hit play/pause on the keyboard
  - Does not work if I hit play/pause over Bluetooth using a speaker or my car's steering wheel
- .NET Windows Forms

  - "Keylogger" works great, but same problem with NodeJS: It does not listen for "keypresses" from a Bluetooth device

I don't care which language I have to use. I know that it's possible, because if I have Spotify running on my Windows machine and I hit play/pause on my speaker or on my car's steering wheel, it will pause Spotify. So something is definitely listening to the inputs, but I haven't figured out what.

**One very important thing**: It has to listen globally for the Bluetooth events. I do not want to have an application focused.

What language can I use, that can listen for these events? Are there frameworks or libraries out there, that can do this easily already?

Comment: There are some problems with Bluetooth Audio profiles on Windows platforms. Even Win 10 supports HFP, AVRCP and A2DP there is no easy way to access them. However, AVRCP device appears as HID device in the system. So you can work with it as with any other HID device. For such low-level task you need any "low-level" language. I personally prefer Delphi (even it doe snot include all I need). C++ is good too but a bit comples. I'm sure there is enough functional for HID in c# as well. Probably something exists for node.js.

Comment: I forgot to say that all I wrote above is true for Microsoft Bluetooth drivers running on Windows 10 (probably on Win 8 as well, but not sure that all features are available there). If your tablet uses other Bluetooth drivers then there is other solutions.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks for the reply. I'm using a Surface Go tablet, so it's pretty much stock. So I would have to investigate how the Bluetooth HID communicates and see if I can intercept/analyze data sent to/from the Bluetooth connected speaker/car?

Comment: Speaker is much simple than buttons. When you connected to your car (I mean tablet connected) new Audio device appeared in the system. You can use any multimedia API to access it and control audio data. Buttons is a bit complex. Unfortunately I can not find any information for AVRCP HID mapping so you have to inestigate it.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Gotcha okay. Isn't the car the same as a regular Bluetooth speaker? A Bluetooth speaker (pick any speaker) might have play/pause, skip track, previous track, volume control, and so on. Wouldn't these map 1:1 to a car? I'm assuming that when I hit play/pause on my car's display or steering wheel, it would send the same Bluetooth signal/command to the connected device.

Comment: It depends on Bluetooth Profile used. Usualy car uses HFP (HandsFree) to provide calls. However in your case it looks like it uses A2DP (Advanced Audio Distribution Profile) together with AVRCP (Audio Video Remote Control) if so then yes, it is the same as your Bluetooth speakers. You can easy check which profiles are available with Android Bluetooth Profile Scanner application running on your Android cell (if you use iPhone there should be something similar)

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Ah interesting! In Windows Universal apps, there's apparently something called `SystemMediaTransportControls`. A colleague of mine recently made a similar application, and he told me his Windows application works with play/pause from his Bluetooth headset. So I'll definitely look at that and make a "proof of concept keylogger" that will log all media control events. I can't specifically find any documentation about AVRCP and the SystemMediaTransportControls class, but I'm pretty sure it should be possible.

Comment: Yes, this class looks as what you need. It should use AVRCP internally. But any way I do recommend to look on HID as well. It gives yo umore control becasue does not require Media Player. I mean in case of HID you can play music in your app without using Media Player or something else so all the process will be under your application control. But that class is good starting point.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Definitely. So with HID I don't specifically need some media to be playing, correct? I wonder if there's a class for that as well hmm. There probably is haha

Comment: Yes, with HID you can simple send and receive commands/information. Probably yes, but HID is just a specification. Each device (device tpyes: mouse, keyboard, remote control) has own HID packet format. So the problem is to find how AVRCP commands are mapped/encoded to/in HID packets.